# How to sum two input fields

Tags: jquery, input

I have following layout in an html table:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Id</td><td>Item Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Shampoo</td><td>200</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Soap</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Toothpaste</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>Others</td><td><input class="ta" type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>Total</td><td><input id="tp" type="text" value="228" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Data of table rows are fetched from mysql database except 5th row (Item:Others). While page loads, value of "Total" is also fetched from mysql database. If an user put any value to "Others" row, everytime the value of "Total" should sum the user input value + value of "Total" row.

I am trying to do this by the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ta").keyup(function(){
  var vat = $(this).val();
    var total = $("#tp").val();
        total = vat+total;
    $("#tp").val(total);
});
});
```

However, it is not doing the sum of two value, instead it is adding the input value. i,g: If total is 5,000 and user input 50, it can't calculate total as 5050, instead it is changing total value as 505000. I think any of these two fields are evaluating as text instead digit by jquery.

What should be the right code?

Comment: there are no elements with class `ta`

Comment: Sorry, that was typing mistake. It will be class. I corrected it. But it has no effects.

Answer (score 3):

you need to parse those textboxes values before adding them. you will also need to modify the input element selector. `ta` is id of element. you should use id selector(`#`):

```
$("#ta").keyup(function(){
var vat = parseInt($(this).val());
var total = parseInt($("#tp").val());
    total = vat+total;
$("#tp").val(total);
});
```

Comment: Not working. What it is doing, If I put 5 in "ta" field it, firstly it removes the value of "tp" field and put 5 there, If I put another 5 (to add 55) in "ta" field, it add it before 5 (not doing sum).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ta").keyup(function(){
  var vat = $('#ta').val();
    var total = $("#tp").val();
        total = vat+total;
    $("#tp").val(total);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `class` selector instead use `id` selector(because there is no element with class `ta` in your HTML structure) and use `parseInt()` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ta").keyup(function(){  //  <-----correct here
    var vat = parseInt( $(this).val(),10 ) || 0;  // <------use parseInt() here
    var total = parseInt( $("#tp").val(),10 ) || 0; // <------use parseInt() here
        total = vat+total;
    $("#tp").val(total);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use psrseInt javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ta").keyup(function(){
 var vat = parseInt($(this).val());
 var total = parseInt($("#tp").val());
 $("#tp").val(vat+total);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of `total` in a variable else you will loose the original value.

Also to add the values of textfields(which are strings), you need to convert them to int(using unary plus or parseInt())

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //store the initial value
  var total = +$("#tp").val() || 0;
  $("#ta").keyup(function() {
    var vat = +$(this).val() || 0;
    $("#tp").val(vat + total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Shampoo</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Soap</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Toothpaste</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Others</td>
    <td>
      <input id="ta" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>
      <input id="tp" type="text" value="228" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I found why it is not working incase of me. Actually the initial value fetched from database in "#tp" has delimeter (,). So it can't do sum, instead it is just coping the "#ta" value to "#tp" value. How to resolve it. (n.b: it will be better if resulting summation has also a delimeter after keyup). I have added a delimeter in your code and look your jquery is not working properly.