# How to subtract two inputs with each another

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I subtract two text inputs from the main input? For example if I inserted `100` in the `total` input and then inserted `20` in `v1` and `30` in `v2`, the `total` input should change to `50`. This what I've tried

```js
function updateDue() {
  var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value);
  var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value);

  var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
  ansD.value = ansD.value - val1 - val2;
}
```

```html
<input id="total" type="text " >
<input id="v1" type="text" onchange="updateDue()>
<input id="v2" type="text" onchange="updateDue()>
```

Comment: Please show any code attempts you have made so far

Comment: And what you tried so far?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service, please show what you have tried yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum two input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241808/how-to-sum-two-input-fields)

Comment: Your function does not contain any jQuery. do you want to use plain JS or jQuery?

Comment: `ansD.value = val1 - val2;` try it

Comment: plain js, munim this way i will neglect the value in the total field

Comment: Your HTML is missing the closing `"` in the `onchange` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="total" type="text">
<input id="v1" type="text">
<input id="v2" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="update()">Update</button>
<script>
function update() {
  var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
  var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value, 10);
  var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value, 10);
  document.getElementById("total").value = total - (value1 + value2);
}
</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/md9ebo00/5/

I would not suggest using `onchange="update"` as an attribute for the two value fields, as when you type in the first value, you will wipe out your original total before you've typed in the second value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateDue(){
   var first = $('#v1').val();
   var second = $('#v2').val();
   var before = $('#total').val();
   var total=parseInt(before)-(parseInt(first)+parseInt(second));
   $('#total').val(total);
}
```

Comment: if you using onchange function then you need to check is there any undefined values.